# Show video length in HLS player before all TS files are created

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have a spring-boot backend which on request (on demand) uses ffmpeg to create a m3u8 playlist with its ts files from a mp4 file. So basically my react frontend requests the index.m3u8 from the backend and if it doesnt already exist it creates it and then start serving it with its ts files. This causes the frontend HLS player to show the length of the video to the combined length of the generated chunks which gets longer as time goes on until its fully there. It totally makes sense but was wondering what the correct way of showing the full length in the player even though its not fully created yet?

Im using react-hls-player for playing the stream and spring-boot + a java ffmpeg wrapper to transcode the video.

Might be thinking about this the wrong way so feel free to correct me if im in the wrong path!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using HLS at all?  Are you transcoding to different bitrates on the fly as well?

Answer (score 0):

> It totally makes sense but was wondering what the correct way of showing the full length in the player even though its not fully created yet?

Well, think about this in layers.  The HLS knows *at most* what is available in the playlist.  The playlist only contains the segments that have been output thus far.  So, there's nothing to be done on the playback side.  You would have to get this information from the input side and show it in your UI, completely independent of this extra streaming mechanism.